# What is the Veil mentioned in Hebrews 6:19?

Tags: hebrews, temple, tabernacle

What is the **veil** mentioned in

> **Hebrews 6:19** which hope we have as an anchor of the soul, both sure
>   and stedfast, and which entereth into that within the **veil**;

?

Was not the veil to the Holy of Holies removed/torn when this book was written?

Answer (score 3):

The Bible use of "veil" is quite consistent throughout the Bible as the following analysis shows.

The Old Testament Hebrew word for veil, פָּרֹ֫כֶת (paroketh), occurs just 24 times and always denotes the division between the Holy & Most Holy Place in the sanctuary, viz, Ex 26:31; 35:12; 36:35; 38:27; 39:34; 40:3, 21; Lev 21:23; Num 4:5; 2 Chron 3:14.

“Before the veil” always denotes the Holy Place, viz, Ex 26:35; 27:21; 30:6; 40:22, 26; Lev 4:6, 17; 24:3

“Within the veil” always denotes the Most Holy Place, viz, Ex 26:33 (twice); Lev 16:2, 12, 15; Num 18:7

The New Testament Greek word for veil is καταπέτασμα (katapetasma), which occurs only 6 times, the first four of which consistently denote the division between the Holy & Most Holy Place in the earthly sanctuary:  Matt 27:51; Mark 15:38; Luke 23:45; Heb 9:3.

For hermeneutic consistency, Heb 6:19 & 20; and Heb 10:19 & 20 about the heavenly sanctuary should denote something similar, even if used metaphorically of the heavenly sanctuary.  (As the OP correctly observes, this reference cannot be to the earthly tabernacle/sanctuary which was destroyed in 70 AD.  With the exception of a few verses, most of the references to the sanctuary in Hebrews refers to the heavenly sanctuary as Heb 9:11 makes clear.

Comment: Thank you @Dottard, So are you saying that there is a veil in the heavenly sanctuaryt still?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The heavenly temple is nowhere described so we do not know what it looks like.  "behind the veil" more likely means that Jesus, as our high priest" has entered within the veil and thus was formally installed as our mediator (2 Tim 2:5, Heb 4:14-16, etc).  Now a way to God has been made available.

Answer (score 2):

**What is the Veil mentioned in Hebrews 6:19?**

Hebrews 6:19 which hope we have as an anchor of the soul, both sure and stedfast, and which entereth into that within the veil;

The veil/ curtain separated the Holy Place  from the  Most Holy in the Tabernacle.

Exodus 26:31-33  (NASB)

The Veil and Screen

> 31 “You shall make a veil of blue and purple and scarlet material and
>   fine twisted linen; it shall be made with cherubim, the work of a
>   skillful workman. 32 You shall hang it on four pillars of acacia
>   overlaid with gold, their hooks also being of gold, on four [c]sockets
>   of silver. 33 You shall [d]hang up the veil under the clasps, and
>   shall bring in the ark of the testimony there within the veil; and the
>   veil shall serve for you as a partition between the holy place and the
>   holy of holies.

The veil/Curtain  was a barrier separating the Holy place from the Most Holy; in Jesus’ case it represented “his flesh,” which he had to lay down in sacrifice, giving it up forever, to be able to enter heaven,  Paul wrote, **"through the veil, that is, His flesh"**

Hebrews 10:19-20 (NASB)

> 19 "Therefore, brethren, since we have confidence to enter the holy
>   place by the blood of Jesus, 20 by a new and living way which He
>   inaugurated for us **through the veil, that is, His flesh."**

Anointed Christians must also pass the fleshly barrier that separates them from access to God’s presence in heaven. Consistently, the Holy represents their condition as spirit-begotten sons of God, with heavenly life in view, and they will attain to that heavenly reward when their fleshly bodies are laid aside in death.

1 Corinthians 15:50  (NASB)

> 50 "Now I say this, brethren, that flesh and blood cannot inherit the
>   kingdom of God; nor does the perishable inherit the imperishable."

​1 Peter 3:18 (NASB)

> 18 "For Christ also died for sins once for all, the just for the
>   unjust, so that He might bring us to God, having been put to death in
>   the flesh, but made alive in the spirit;"

John 6:51 (NASB)

> 51 "I am the living bread that came down out of heaven; if anyone eats
>   of this bread, **he will live forever;** and the bread also which I will
>   give for the life of the world is **My flesh."**

Answer (score 0):

'entering within the veil' doesn't seem to exclude splitting it, from top to bottom.
The Son of Man entered the Father in resurrection, Jn 14:12, splitting the veil of His flesh and becoming "a life-giving Spirit," 1 Cor 15:45. Now, "he who is joined to the Lord is one spirit," 1 Cor 6:17. His Spirit, joined to our spirit, is the anchor to 
believers' souls, 1 Thes 5:23; Rm 8:16; Jn 4:24.

Answer (score 0):

There is no temple in the New Jerusalem and there are no veils to divide and separate us from God and from each other.

Comment: @ Linda Burns - Thank you for responding. However, some more research needs to be done, especially the use of Biblical scriptures  to back up statements. (See other Answerer's use of verses.)  It is true that the Old Temple was to be a "type" or symbol of the amazing New Temple. And so any new reference in the New Covenant is merely metaphorical.  Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!